# What does "printing the current print status" means in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a printer manual and can't understand the meaning of the phrase "printing the current print status" in this  sentence:

> After **printing the current print status**, a continuing self-test guidance is printed, and the Paper LED flashes.

Answer (score 1):

This message appears in the manual for an Epson receipt or label printer. The "print status" is the status of the printer. Since it probably doesn't have a large display (if it has any display at all), and it is after all *a printer*, it makes sense that the printer can output status information by printing it out on paper. **Printing the current print status** means printing out a piece of paper on which the status of the printer (and probably other diagnostic information) is written.

It is worth noting that technical manuals and user guides for consumer products are **notorious** in English-speaking countries for often being *very* poorly written. They are often written by non-native speakers in foreign countries, or worse, are very low quality translations from other languages, such as Chinese or Japanese. Sometimes they are even translations-of-translations. This is often true even for major brand-name manufacturers. *This **does not** appear to be the case for this particular manual,* but if you read enough of these manuals you are sure to run into some very bad English indeed.